# How to do recursive loops in scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering if there is a better way to write recursive loops in scala.

```
def fib(n: Int) = {
  def loop(a: BigInt = 0, b: BigInt = 1, n: Int = n): BigInt = {
    if(n==0) a
    else loop(b, a+b, n-1)
  }
  loop()
}
```

I could write it like this

```
def fib(n: Int, a: BigInt = 0, b: BigInt = 1): BigInt = {
  if(n==0) a
  else fib(n-1, b, a+b)
}
```

but then a and b would be exposed and not encapsulated inside the method anymore.

Comment: That's pretty much how it's done (the first example). The inner `def` also ensure it's private and can be optimized for tail cails.

Comment: The second version is tail recursive too. I asked about the possibility of adding some way to make these parameters private of the Scala Language mailing list in August and was met with a deafening silence / lack of interest. http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10736

Comment: What does it mean `making the parameters private`? That they can't be used from outside? For which reason? Fibonacci-like sequences are possible with different start values - I'm pretty sure I've seen such things.

Comment: @userunknown Yes. Because they are an implementation detail and not part of the API design. In the examples above, the first is better in terms of separating the API from the implementation, but the second is nicer in terms of conciseness and clarity. What would be good would be if we could combine the advantages of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can often use `foldLeft` or `foldRight` in such situations:

```
def fib(n: Int) = (1 to n).foldLeft((BigInt(0),BigInt(1)))((p,_)=>(p._2,p._1+p._2))._1
```

**[Edit]**

Another approach would be an iterator-based solution:

```
def fib = Iterator.iterate((0,1)){case (x,y) => (y,x+y)}.map(_._1)
```

This generates an infinite amount of fibonacci numbers, but you can simply take as many as you want from it, e.g. `fib.take(10).toList`

Answer (score 1):

Loops have their own scopes. When you replace a loop with a recursive function you are forced to create an explicit scope (the inner method). There is no way around it. This is how it is done. Nothing wrong about it.